# Discarding specific faces in shaders

Tags: glsl

I am trying to hide a specific face (assuming face 0) by using the `discard` keyword.

Vertex Shader:

```
uniform float v_triangleId;
varying vec3 normal;

void main() {
   v_triangleId = floor(gl_VertexID / 3.0);

   normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
   gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Pixel Shader:

```
uniform float v_triangleId;

void main(void)
{   
    float diff = abs(v_triangleId - 0); // I just want to hide face 0
    if (diff < 0.01) {
        discard;
    }
}
```

However, in this case all the faces are hidden, instead of just a single face. I was wondering what went wrong.

Comment: "*I am trying to hide a specific face*" Do you only ever intend to discard faces built with the first 3 vertices? Or do you have some other criteria in mind?

Comment: @NicolBolas My intent is to hide all faces that has the face index. (i.e. `v_triangleId` should be an array). But to simplify the question I am now assuming the hidden face is the first 3 vertices only.

Comment: Is that criteria something the VS can compute? Don't forget to take into account that faces can share vertices.

Comment: @NicolBolas I would think so. I am following the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28471031/2164904